# Laravel 5.4: How do I validate an image size?

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-5.4

I have a form where a user can submit an image. I don't want to store it on my server in case it's a virus but instead store it to Amazon S3.

My issue is that I need to validate if the image is less than a specific dimension. 
How can I do that in Laravel 5.4?

My controller

```
 $validator = \Validator::make($request->all(),[
    "logo"      => "dimensions:max_width:300,max_height:200",
 ]);

 if($validator->fails()){
    return \Redirect::back()->withInput()->withErrors( $validator );
 }
```

The validation fails and redirects back with "The logo has invalid image dimensions." eventhough the image i'm uploading is 100x100.
What's the correct way to validate or what are alternate solutions without having to save the file?

Comment: Are you sure your form is method=POST and has `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute, and the "logo" field is a file input?

Comment: Did you save the file before the validation reach?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

use equals sign (**=**) rather than colon (**:**) with `max_width` & `max_height` :

```
"logo"  => "dimensions:max_width=300,max_height=200",
```

[Image dimension validation rules in Laravel](https://mattstauffer.com/blog/image-dimension-validation-rules-in-laravel-5-3/)

---

If it doesn't solve, make sure that your form has `enctype="multipart/form-data"` (as mentioned in comment by [@F.Igor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4195981/f-igor)):

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="logo">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

If you already using this, then check (before validation) whether you are getting image with your request and with what name:

```
dd($request->all())
```

Comment: Thanks it was the enctype missing. Having the colons actually still worked.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a validation example for:

- Image formats
- Max file size
- Dimensions

```
$request->validate([
     'avatar' => ['image','mimes:jpg,png,jpeg,gif','max:200','dimensions:min_width=100,min_height=100,max_width500,max_height=500'],
]);
```

`max:200` (200kb max size limit)